# Azure Data Factory Lookup Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've got a Data Factory Lookup Activity
The left (Primary) and right (Lookup Stream) side need to match on 4 columns to lookup a result.
I've got;

```
toString(byName('Col1')) == toString(byName('Col1'))
toString(byName('Col2')) == toString(byName('Col2'))
...
```

I've also tried referencing the datasets

```
toString(byName('Col1','LeftSideDataset')) == toString(byName('Col1','RightSideDataset'))
```

When I preview the data in debugging I'm expecting those Columns to match, and the additional columns from the right to be added but they don't, they all seem to have matched the first row in the left input (without all of the matching criteria).

Has anyone experienced this?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

Hi Dan what settings did you use,
I could not understand correctly , does anything Match from the Rightside or nothing ?

[image]

If only some match, might try it with the Match multiple rows or the Broadcasting

As the Debug shows only some examples of Data, it may occur that only the first lookup that hits is shown

[image]

Comment: Hi smotorious,

Thanks for the answer - it was not finding anything (even outside of debug).
I've since been able to track it back - someone changed a Linked Source so it was querying a different environment without the data I was expecting.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

The data flow works as expected.
The data wasn't showing as a Linked Service was altered so the data wasn't as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).